# How to loop through date variable names and sum by group?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some time series data where there are a few region variables and the rest of the variable names are all dates. I am trying to trying to loop through the entire list of date variables and sum each of them but am unsure how to do it using dplyr syntax. This is what I have so far

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
library(curl)

# county level
covid_jhu <- as.data.frame(fread(paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_US.csv")))

# remove territories and assign the correct FIPS code
covid_jhu <- covid_jhu %>%
  filter(Admin2 != "") %>%
  mutate(FIPS = substr(as.character(UID), 4, 8))

jhu_state <- covid_jhu %>%
  group_by(Province_State) %>%
  mutate(`1/22/20` = sum(`1/22/20`))
```

I can't seem to figure out the loop here even though I seem to be able to get it right for 1 variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is potential method to perform the desired grouping.  The key is convert the wide data frame from the source and transform it into a long format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


# county level
covid_jhu <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_US.csv")

# remove territories and assign the correct FIPS code
covid_jhu <- covid_jhu %>%
  filter(Admin2 != "") %>%
  mutate(FIPS = substr(as.character(UID), 4, 8))

#convert from wide to long
long_covid_jhu<-pivot_longer(covid_jhu, cols=starts_with("X"), names_to = "Date")
long_covid_jhu$Date <- as.Date(long_covid_jhu$Date, format="X%m.%d.%y")


#grouping by state
long_covid_jhu %>%
  group_by(Province_State) %>% summarize(TotalCases=sum(value))

#grouping by date
long_covid_jhu %>%
  group_by(Date) %>% summarize(TotalCases=sum(value))

#grouping by state & date
long_covid_jhu %>%
  group_by(Province_State, Date) %>% summarize(TotalCases=sum(value))
```

Comment: The line `long_covid_jhu<-pivot_longer(covid_jhu, cols=starts_with("X"), names_to = "Date")` just returns an error as no columns are selected.

Comment: @ANam, Since, I used `read.csv` to read retrieve the file(thus avoiding loading the data.table package), headers were converted from dates to character strings starting with the "X"

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. I just used

`for (i in 12:length(names(covid_jhu))) {
  names(covid_jhu)[i] <- paste0("X", names(covid_jhu)[i])
}

#convert from wide to long

covid_jhu<-pivot_longer(covid_jhu, cols=starts_with("X"), names_to = "Date")

covid_jhu$Date <- substr(covid_jhu$Date, 2, nchar(covid_jhu$Date))

covid_jhu$Date <- as.Date(covid_jhu$Date, format = "%m/%d/%y")`

Comment: or you could have substituted in `cols=12:length(names(covid_jhu)`

Answer (score 0):

Suggest if you want to try functions like

- **group_by_all**,
- **group_by_** (this take a variable name as input rather than hard-coding a column name, essentially you can keep passing column names as input in a loop)
- Similarly, you will have **mutate_** , **summarise_** functions as well

With my understanding of the question, i think reading slightly about this solves your purpose